# Múltiplos layouts em uma só activity - como utilizar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como nesse trecho:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addcontact);

    imageButton01 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imageButton01.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == imageButton01) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {   
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                
                imageButton01.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } 
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de utilizar o mesmo esquema de tirar fotos através dos imageButton, utilizando dois layouts, com a mesma Activity?

Infelizmente, a sintaxe "setContentView();" autoriza apenas uma por vez.

PS.: Estou utilizando o Eclipse do ADT Bundle para desenvolvimento em Android.

EDIT.: Seguem abaixo os dois .xml relativos às telas:

Adicionar contato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addFirstName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="103dip"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="First name" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addFirstName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="103dip"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Last name"
        android:width="190dip" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addLastName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="103dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtAux5"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Phone number"
        android:width="190dip" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addPhone"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:onClick="btnSave_click"
            android:text="Save">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addPhone"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Cancel" >
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="103dip"
        android:layout_height="103dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addFirstName"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Editar contato:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtFirstName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="103dip"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="First name" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtLastName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtFirstName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="103dip"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Last name"
    android:width="190dip" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtLastName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="103dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtAux5"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Phone number"
    android:width="190dip" >
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtPhone"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="btnConfirm_click"
        android:text="Confirm">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:src="@drawable/delete" 
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete" 
        android:text=" Delete " 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtPhone"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Cancel" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="103dip"
    android:layout_height="103dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edtFirstName"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar" />
```

Comment: O que é que você quer dizer com "dois layouts"?

Comment: Duas telas. Criei dois xml, um para criar e outro para adicionar o contato e gostaria de utilizar o mesmo método tanto para adicionar uma foto quanto para alterá-la.

Comment: Meu caro amigo @LeoS, você só pode ter um layout para sua Atividade, e também não teria motivo pra querer dois layout's em uma atividade só, qual seria o seu objetivo?

Comment: @LeoS, você pode utilizar o mesmo layout para fazer isto, porém você pode esconder/mostrar elementos de acordo com o estado se é edição ou criação

Comment: Você editar sua pergunta e postar os dois Layout's para que eu possa lhe mostrar um meio de fazer?

Comment: Post editado com os dois layouts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A Difereça entre seus Layout's

Pelo que vejo, você tem dois Layout's praticamente iguais, com apenas algumas alterações mínimas (as ID's), fora os ID's seria o botão `btnSave` e o `btnConfirm` que são iguais porém com texto diferente, e também um `ImageButton` que você adicionou no "Editar contato".

## Comentários em relação às diferenças

Você não precisa realizar as alterações de ID's você pode realmente usar o Layout do "Editar Contato" para os dois, pois são elementos iguais, com exceção do `btnConfirm` e da `imageButton`, porém isto é facil de resolver.

## Conclusão e resolução do problema

Facilmente você pode fazer o seguinte, caso for adição de contato, altere o texto do `btnSave` para "Confirm" do contrário permaneça como está por padrão que seria "Save"

```java
if (isEdicao){
  Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
  btnSave.setText("Confirm");
}
```

Tendo em vista que o padrão do Layout será "Adicionar Contato" você deve esconder o ImageButton por padrão também, pois ele deve apenas aparecer ser for Edição:

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="103dip"
    android:layout_height="103dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addFirstName"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Note que eu adicionei a propriedade `android:visibility="gone"` para se tornar invisível e inexistente(não representa espaço).

O Código ficaria assim:

```java
if (isEdicao){
  Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
  btnSave.setText("Confirm");
  ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
  imgButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**Por isso você não deve e não precisa ter 2 Layout's apenas um Layout você pode utilizar mudando textos e escondendo/mostrando elementos para se comportar de acordo.**

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Tenho só mais uma dúvida. Ao criar o contato, o imageButton deve vir com o ícone inicial, para que o usuário possa adicionar logo de início, se assim desejar. Porém, ao clicar no contato em uma lista para editá-lo, ele deve também ter a possibilidade de ver a foto atual e alterá-la. Portanto, não posso simplesmente deixar o imageButton desabilitado logo de ínicio. Conhece alguma forma de realizar isso?

Comment: Você pode ter uma condição para habilitar o imageButton, porém não entendi em quais situações você quer habilita-lo

Comment: Eu quero que ele permaneça habilitado, mas em duas situações diferentes. Para criar o contato e adicionar uma imagem nova. E para editar, tendo a opção de alterar a atual. Estou fazendo uma agenda de contatos.

Comment: adicione uma variável booleana no começo de sua atividade onde ficam as variáveis da classe Activity como private chamada `isAdicionandoImagemNova = false` por exemplo, e sete para true quando você clicar para adicionar uma imagem nova, e então cheque se for true você mostra o imageButton e seta a booleana pra false. E pra editar ela já não aparece?

Comment: Vou tentar, é uma ideia boa. Por enquanto não, preciso descobrir como farei pra pegar a imagem do banco de dados e transferir para o imageButton ainda.

Comment: qualquer coisa poste outra pergunta referente a isto :)